# Audiokit MIDI device for IOS

Tags: audiokit

Is it possible to identify the MIDI device(s) connected (IOS version) when using the camera kit. I don't see a function for that although you can specify a name when starting the MIDI output. I'm guessing there is a way to get a name somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if you're using class compliant MIDI to usb converters the MIDI devices will register automatically. There is nothing that is specific to the camera connection kit.

Comment: I have been able to connect two USB/MIDI devices successfully using the camera kit and a hub. Is there a way to identify the devices connected?

Comment: All of the midi connections ie. endpoints have associated endpoint info including the name and manufacturer: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/MIDI/AKMIDIEndpointInfo.swift